# Create SSLContext for RabbitMQ configuration with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-rabbit

I need to create and set a SSLContext to connect to a RabbitMQ queue with Spring framework. I use the @RabbitListener annotation and without SSLContext, by setting hostname, port, username and password into the application.properties file, all the things works just perfect.

But how can I manually set a SSLContext? The application.properties want a JKS and I can't use it. I see some configurations beans but what I found online is not clear at all.

How can I configure manually/programmatically (SSLContext precisly) RabbitMQ on Spring framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that extends `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean` and override `createSSLContext()`.

```java
/**
 * Override this method to create and/or configure the {@link SSLContext} used
 * by the {@link ConnectionFactory}.
 * @return The {@link SSLContext}.
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException if the algorithm is not available.
 * @since 1.4.4
 */
protected SSLContext createSSLContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return SSLContext.getInstance(this.sslAlgorithm);
}
```

Then declare a `CachingConnectionFactory` bean that uses the rabbit connection factory created by the factory bean.

Comment: Great! Perfect answer!